# Pagination in GetDatabaseNames function in RavenDB

Tags: database, pagination, ravendb

I am using RavenDB build 701 and in GetDatabaseNames(int pageSize) function I need to get 5 database at a time. It is very easy to get number of databases but if I want next 5 databases and so on then I couldn't find any pagination scheme with this function. please tell me the right way to do this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Rajdeep,
This is currently not supported in the API.
You can do a direct http request to http://raven-server/databases/?pageSize=5&start=5

(give me 5 - 10 databases)

Comment: Thank you for the way.How can I use direct http request in c# code. Please tell me